# SAS date variable

Tags: date, sas

I have a SAS data set A and one of the column is date. 31AUG2010. when I do the following code:

```
data b;
set a;
newdate=date;
run;
```

The newdate becomes numeric and 31AUG2010 becomes 18505. How do I solve it?

Comment: DATE is numeric, and has a format associated that allows you to see the value in a way you can interpret.  The format is DATE9.  If you associated that format with NEWDATE you will be enlightened.

Comment: Your Question is genuine and fine, there was no need for the down vote, I'll up vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a format. 
See the example below with two different formats applied.

```
data b;
set a;
newdate=date;
newdate2 = date;

format newdate date9. newdate2 ddmmyy10.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are just the number of days from 01JAN1960.  You need to apply a format.  A format doesn't change how the number is stored, just how it is presented to you.

```
Data a;
set a;
format newdate date9.;
newdate=date;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a date format to the new field. Since Date is a numeric field in SAS; SAS assigns the default format which is numeric.

You can assign the format by adding a format statement

```
data test;
format newdate date9.;
date='31AUG2010'd;
newdate=date;
run;
```

date has no format assigned but newdate has date9. format assigned.

Output:

```
newdate=31AUG2010 date=18505
```